# Show, submit and process form inside of Magnific Popup and refresh content

Tags: jquery, forms, magnific-popup

### Edit

**Is there anybody who can give me a working example of a form including submitting inside of a Magnific Popup? I think I just need an example to get one step further... Thank you!**

---

I try to switch from Colorbox to Magnific Popup because of the lack of responsiveness. Images and Galleries work as a charm, but I can't figure out how to work with forms inside of a Magnific Popup.

That's how it should work:

1. Open Magnific Popup after User clicks on a Link. -> works fine
2. Show a little form (in my case: just one select list and the submit button) and below the form, show the current content (i.e. some text or image coming from the database) -> works fine
3. When the user selects another option of the select list and submits the form, the PHP code to process the form input should be called and the content below the form should be updated based on the selected option. -> does not work!
4. The popup should remain opened until the user clicks on the close icon (no page reload) -> does not work!
5. The optimal solution of my dreams would make the submit button unnecessary by submitting the form directly after selecting another option inside of the select field (onchange). But for now, I would be very happy to get things work even with a submit button...!

The whole thing worked perfectly with Colorbox, but I am not able to submit the form without loosing the Magnific Popup and getting redirected to the PHP script itself...

Below is some code. Is there somebody out there who can show me a working example code for showing a form inside of Magnific Popup and replacing its content (or the content of a div inside of the popup) after submitting and processing the form?

Many thanks!!!

HTML Link to open the Magnific Popup:

```
<a class="magnificpopup_ajax" href="form_code.php">Open Form</a>
```

jQuery-Code (on the same page like the HTML link):

```
$('.magnificpopup_ajax').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',
  callbacks: {
    change: function() {
      console.log('Content changed');
      console.log(this.content);
    },
    updateStatus: function(data) {
      console.log('Status changed', data);
      if (data.stauts == 'ready') {
        console.log('fire mpform_submit');
        mpform_submit();
      }
    }
  }
});

function mpform_submit() {
  $('#s_xyz').change(function(){
    console.log('change function fired...');
    return false;
  });
}
```

form_code.php (simplified):

```
<?php
require_once ('functions.php');
if (isset($_POST['s_xyz']) && !empty($_POST['s_xyz'])) {
  // Form submitted
  $form_selected = htmlspecialchars($_POST['s_xyz']);
}
else {
  $form_selected = 'current';
}

// some database queries to get content based on $form_selected...
// ...

$output = '<p>Database content based on form_selected ('. $form_selected .')</p>';

// Form
$form = '
  <form id="formid" action="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'" method="post">
    <label for="s_xyz">your selection:</label>
    <select id="s_xyz" name="s_xyz" id="s_xyz" size="1">
      <option value="current">current content</option>
      <option value="option4">option 1</option>
      <option value="option4">option 2</option>
      <option value="option4">option 3</option>
      <option value="option4">option 4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="send" />
  </form>';

// Output
echo '
  <div style="max-width:1000px; margin: 20px auto; background-color: white;">
    '. $form .'
    '. $output .'
  </div>';
?>
```

The original working Colorbox jQuery code looks like this:

```
function cbox_submit() {
  $('#s_xyz').change(function(){
    $.post(
      $('#formid').attr('action'),
      $('#formid').serialize(),
      function(data){
        $().colorbox({
          html: data,
          title: '&nbsp;',
          scalePhotos: false,
          width: $('#cboxWrapper').width(),
          height: $('#cboxWrapper').height(),
          onComplete: function(){
            $('#cboxTitle').html($('#cb_CaptionTitle').html());
            cbox_submit();
          }
        });
      }
    );
    return false;
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var screenW = window.outerWidth;
  if (screenW < 880) { cbWidth = screenW - 40; }
  else { cbWidth = 840; }

  $('.colorbox_ajax').colorbox({
    width: cbWidth,
    height: 400,
    title: '&nbsp;',
    scalePhotos: false,
    onComplete:function(){
      $('#cboxTitle').html($('#cb_CaptionTitle').html());
      cbox_submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: do not bind any event in a function call. It will bind the event at number of times of function call.

Comment: @Jai Many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I do not understand what you mean...? Which event did I bind?